# Image on Canvas is drawn larger than original size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

On load of my image I:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = e.target.result;
var canvas = $('#test-canvas')[0];
$('#test-canvas').width(img.width);
$('#test-canvas').height(img.height);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

But the image is drawn larger than it's original size? I've tried a few images, same problem.

What's the fix?

Comment: Try including the wanted height and width on the canvas call:
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height): 
[Canvas Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)

Comment: greendave11 - nope, still the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery will resize the element through CSS, which won't actually change the canvas internal height and width. This will resize the actual canvas element.

```
var canvas = document.GetElementById('test-canvas');
canvas.width  = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
```

jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/L0drfwgL/) just show it drawing it to scale, and resizing the canvas item itself.

Comment: As stated in my questions: "On load of my image I" ive also logged width/height to be sure it's correct

Comment: But I log the width and height upon load and it's all correct.

Comment: I'll add this edit later. But I just realized that you're using the wrong sizing call on the canvas element. Don't use jQuery for this. Just write `canvas.width = img.width` jQuery is changing the CSS style.

Comment: I think you may have it with your last comment. Will accept once tested.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are pulling the image from an image element on load. You can use the src from the image element rather than recreating an image object and then get the image width/height from the element to draw the image to canvas.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#testImg').on('load',function(){
            var image = document.getElementById('testImg');
            var canvas = document.getElementById('test-canvas');
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
        })
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/** with vue3 -(to fix drawing canvas image is larger than actual image size **/
const captureImage = () => {
  let width = video.value.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let height = video.value.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  let context = canvas.value.getContext('2d')
  canvas.value.width = width
  canvas.value.height = height
  context.drawImage(video.value, 0, 0, width, height)
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with your answer.